# If equal requires string conversion to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

It seems that `@original_id` and `comment.id` have to be converted to strings to compare equal, when I don't convert them to strings, the string in the `else` branch is returned. Why is this? And is there a way round it?

```
- if @original_id.to_s == comment.id.to_s
    = "Matched"
- else
    = "hi"
```

Context:

```
.comment{:class => "c" + nesting.to_s}
    .profile
        %img{:src => "/assets/profile_image_sample.jpg"}
    .message
        .username
            - if comment.user.username.blank?
                = comment.user.first_name
            - else
                = comment.user.username 
        = comment.content
        .reply-link
            = link_to "Reply to comment...", post_path(:original_id => comment.id)
            = @original_id.to_s + "and" + comment.id.to_s
- if @original_id.to_s == comment.id.to_s
    = "Matched"
- else
    = "hi"
- if comment.replies.count > 0
    - nesting = nesting + 1
    - comment.replies.each do |comment|
        = render "comment", :comment => comment, :nesting => nesting
```

Comment: Maybe `@original_id` and `comment.id` are of different types?

Comment: Are you extracting `@original_id` from `params[:original_id]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of those two variables is a string, while the other is a number.

A possible cause is that in the controller, all received (posted) parameters are strings. Without explicit conversion, you are passing this value to the view as a string.

And to answer your second question:

Convert @original_id to an integer when setting it in the controller:

```
@original_id = params[:original_id].to_i
```

Comment: perfect, didn't know that posted parameters were strings!